# How to make ActionBar invisible in an activity?

Tags: java, android-actionbar

I want to make the actionBar of my activity invisible. `hide()` does not work for me because it removes the actionBar completely and the activity does not maintain the height of the view after hiding it.

How can I do this?

**EDIT** (code update):

layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/detail_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_dark"
            android:contentDescription="@string/back_button"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_selected_name_surname"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Detail"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:gravity="center|start"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_divider"
        android:layout_below="@id/notification_top_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_color"/>
```

And in activity.java, I simply set the linear layout and divider to INVISIBLE:

```
topBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
topBarDivider.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: @TempiaAndrea Hi Andrea. Yes you are right, updated question with my current code.